# continuous shades on matplotlib 3d surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

In a matplotlib 3D plot, I can set the number of rows/columns that determines the total number of faces visible on the surface with

```
s=ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, color='gray', shade=True, rstride=1,cstride=1)
```

where the lower are the numbers rstride and cstride, the smaller are the faces. Since I am also plotting streamlines/trajectories on this surface, I would like to get rid of the edges of the faces. Now, with

```
s.set_linewidth(0)
```

and setting low values of rstride and cstride I almost get what I want, i.e. an almost continuous changing color on the surface, that gives a good 3D effect.

Unfortunately, the lines stay there, as empty places between the faces. Is there a way to do this? Maybe I am just missing a simple command..

EDIT: the code that generates the surface is lengthy to report it here. I attach a snapshot of the result with the workaround written above.[image: surface with white lines]

Comment: can you include a picture of what you'd like to see and post some sample data + minimal code that demonstrates what you have so far?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried adding `antialiased=False` in there too?

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
```

[image]

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0)
```

[image]

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

[image]