# Symmetric streamplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the streamlines of a magnetic field around a sphere using matplotlib, and it does work quite nicely. However, the resulting image is not symmetric, but it should be (I think).
[image]

This is the code used to generate the image. Excuse the length, but I thought it would be better than just posting a non-working snippet. Also, it's not very pythonic; that's because I converted it from Matlab, which was easier than I expected.

```py
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

def cart2spherical(x, y, z):
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    theta = np.arccos(z/r)
    if r == 0:
        theta = 0
    return (r, theta, phi)

def S(theta, phi):
    S = np.array([[np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi), np.cos(theta)*np.cos(phi), -np.sin(phi)],
                  [np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi), np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi),  np.cos(phi)],
                  [np.cos(theta),             -np.sin(theta),             0]])
    return S

def computeB(r, theta, phi, a=1, muR=100, B0=1):
    delta = (muR - 1)/(muR + 2)
    if r > a:
        Bspherical = B0*np.array([np.cos(theta) * (1 + 2*delta*a**3 / r**3),
                                  np.sin(theta) * (delta*a**3 / r**3 - 1),
                                  0])
        B = np.dot(S(theta, phi), Bspherical)
    else:
        B = 3*B0*(muR / (muR + 2)) * np.array([0, 0, 1])
    return B

Z, X = np.mgrid[-2.5:2.5:1000j, -2.5:2.5:1000j]
Bx = np.zeros(np.shape(X))
Bz = np.zeros(np.shape(X))
Babs = np.zeros(np.shape(X))
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(Z)):
        r, theta, phi = cart2spherical(X[0, i], 0, Z[j, 0])
        B = computeB(r, theta, phi)
        Bx[i, j], Bz[i, j] = B[0], B[2]
        Babs[i, j] = np.sqrt(B[0]**2 + B[1]**2 + B[2]**2)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.streamplot(X, Z, Bx, Bz, color='k', linewidth=0.8*Babs, density=1.3,
               minlength=0.9, arrowstyle='-')
ax.add_patch(Circle((0, 0), radius=1, facecolor='none', linewidth=2))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('off')
fig.savefig('streamlines.pdf', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: Look at the arguments of `streamplot`, this looks like it just chose stream lines badly, but your data is fine.

Comment: @tcaswell I think the underlying issue is the discontinuity of the field at the boundary. In this case I think it's wise to split up the plot into two regions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, for curiosity, why would you want to plot symmetric data? Why plotting half of isn't fine?

Said that, this is a possible hack. You can use mask arrays as Hooked suggested to plot half of it:

```
mask = X>0
BX_OUT = Bx.copy()
BZ_OUT = Bz.copy()
BX_OUT[mask] = None
BZ_OUT[mask] = None
res = plt.streamplot(X, Z, BX_OUT, BZ_OUT, color='k', 
           arrowstyle='-',linewidth=1,density=2)
```

then you save in res the result from streamplot, extract the lines and plot them with the opposite X coordinate.

```
lines = res.lines.get_paths()
for l in lines:
    plot(-l.vertices.T[0],l.vertices.T[1],'k')
```

I used this hack to extract streamlines and arrows from a 2D plot, then apply a 3D transformation and plot it with mplot3d. A picture is in one of my questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963004/continuous-shades-on-matplotlib-3d-surface).

Comment: For a data integrity PoV this is a really upsetting solution.

Comment: I have to agree with @tacaswell I'd rather plot ugly original data  and enhance its visual look than sacrifice data integrity to create artistic looking figure.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from the documentation:

> ```
> density : float or 2-tuple
>     Controls the closeness of streamlines. When density = 1, 
>     the domain is divided into 
>     a 25x25 grid—density linearly scales this grid.
>     Each cell in the grid can have, at most, one traversing streamline.
>     For different densities in each direction, use [density_x, density_y].
> ```

so you are getting aliasing effects between the cells it uses to decide where the stream lines are, and the symmetries of your problem.   You need to carefully choose your grid size (of the data) and the density.

It is also sensitive to where the box boundaries are relative to the top of the sphere.  Is the center of your sphere *on* a data grid point or between the data grid points?  If it is *on* a grid point then the box that contains the center point will be different than the boxes adjacent to it.

I am not familiar with exactly how it decides which stream lines to draw, but I could imagine that it is some sort of greedy algorithm and hence will give different results walking towards the high density region and away density region.

To be clear, you issue is not that the stream lines are *wrong*, they are valid stream lines, it is that you find the result not aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: If I understand this right, this would mean if I choose `density = 1.6`, there'd be 40 cells, 20 for each side, with 25 data points to each cell. The plot still isn't symmetric though.

Comment: As Psirus noted getting the density symmetric doesn't necessarily give you a symmetric plot either. I think the other main problem is streamplot chooses starting points for drawing streamlines in a spiral pattern, you can hack `_gen_starting_points` to customize these. Streamlines are also numerically integrated so one would need to take care in ensuring that the gridded data (from density selection) and starting points are fully symmetrical.

Answer (score 6):

Use a mask to separate the two regions of interest:

```
mask = np.sqrt(X**2+Z**2)<1

BX_OUT = Bx.copy()
BZ_OUT = Bz.copy()
BX_OUT[mask] = None
BZ_OUT[mask] = None
plt.streamplot(X, Z, BX_OUT, BZ_OUT, color='k', 
               arrowstyle='-', density=2)

BX_IN = Bx.copy()
BZ_IN = Bz.copy()
BX_IN[~mask] = None
BZ_IN[~mask] = None
plt.streamplot(X, Z, BX_IN, BZ_IN, color='r', 
               arrowstyle='-', density=2)
```

[image]

The resulting plot isn't *exactly* symmetric, but by giving the algorithm a hint, it's far closer than what you had before. Play with the density of the grid via `meshgrid` and the `density` parameter to achieve the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use physics, instead... The magnetic field is symmetrical with respect to the z (vertical) axis! So you just need two `streamplot`'s:

```
plt.streamplot(X, Z, Bx, Bz, color='k', linewidth=0.8*Babs, density=1.3, minlength=0.9, arrowstyle='-')
plt.streamplot(-X, Z, -Bx, Bz, color='k', linewidth=0.8*Babs, density=1.3, minlength=0.9, arrowstyle='-')
```