# Matplotlib streamplot: equidistant starting points on top edge

Tags: matplotlib

How do I generate equidistant starting points for streamlines on the top edge? Now the streamlines are not equally spaced on the top edge, as in the image below. The image has aspect ratio = 3:1; I used `density = (2,0.67)`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can't. citing the documentation, `streamplot` operates in a way that:

"Each cell in the grid can have, at most, one traversing streamline" ([link](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot))

Usually playing with the parameter `density` helps anyway.

You could always 'manually' integrate each streamline starting from your equispaced points of interest.

In case the data above has an **exact** left-rigth symmetry (Can't be sure by just looking at the pic) you may get a better result with the solution I gave here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252231/symmetric-streamplot-with-matplotlib/16373060#16373060).