# Plotting streamlines in a Matplotlib 3Dplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot streamlines on a plane in a 3D plot using Matplotlib. For the streamlines, I'd like to use the function `streamplot()`, because of its simplicity. Here's a MWE that I modified from the gallery (to attempt the `streamplot()` call):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
plt.streamplot(X, Y, X, Y)
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-10, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
cset = ax.streamplot(X, Y, X, Y, zdir='z', offset=-10, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)
plt.show()
```

The first and second examples work as intended, however, the third example gives me this error:

```
TypeError: streamplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'zdir'
```

which hints to the possibility of this not being implemented. If I check `Axes3D`, the function `streamplot()` I get:

```
In [28]: Axes3D.streamplot
Out[28]: <function matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.streamplot>
```

From which we get that `streamplot()` is the 2D version, and hence can't be directly used in 3D plots.

Is there a way to circumvent this and get a streamlines plane in a 3D plot?

Comment: Where did you get that example from? `streamplot` has no `zdir` argument

Comment: @DavidG I included that call to streamplot kind of by analogy with the other plots. Edited the question. Thanks

Comment: To be more precise here, from printing `Axes3D.streamplot`, which results in `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.streamplot` you see that the `streamplot` function is the one from the 2D axes. It can hence not be used on 3D axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks, I totally missed that. Just assumed it was an Axes3D method and didn't notice that it's actually a 2D method. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: There is already a question in a similar direction: [How to plot a 2d streamline in 3d view in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365069/how-to-plot-a-2d-streamline-in-3d-view-in-matplotlib).