# Painting a surf graph in Python whit several colors

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

The next image

[image]

Can be generated using the next code

The next code

```
#%%

try:
    from IPython import get_ipython

    get_ipython().magic('clear')                # to clear the terminal
    get_ipython().magic('reset -f')             # to reset the kernel
    # get_ipython().magic('matplotlib qt')      # plots out line
    get_ipython().magic('matplotlib', 'inline') # plots in line
    
except:
    pass

import numpy as np 
from numpy import * 

import sympy as smp
from sympy import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

import scipy as scp
from scipy.optimize import *
from scipy.integrate import *

import control as co

# import pandas            as pd 
# import sklearn           as sk
# import math
# import os
# import tarfile
# import urllib

np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True) # number of decimals in the expre.

init_printing(use_unicode=True)                 # to show in pretty symboic

#%%

x , n = symbols( 'x n' )

T = 2*pi

xt = np.arange( 0 , 2*np.pi , 1e-3)
xt = np.array([ xt ])

armo = 50



#%%


a0 = (1/(T))*( integrate( 1 , (x , 0 , T/2) ) +\
              integrate( -1 , (x , T/2 , T) ) )
a0 = simplify(a0)
    
an = (2/(T))*( integrate( 1*cos((2*pi/T)*n*x) , (x , 0 , T/2) ) +\
              integrate( -1*cos((2*pi/T)*n*x) , (x , T/2 , T) ) )
an = simplify(an)

bn = (2/(T))*( integrate( 1*sin((2*pi/T)*n*x) , (x , 0 , T/2) ) +\
              integrate( -1*sin((2*pi/T)*n*x) , (x , T/2 , T) ) )
bn = simplify(bn)

#%%

S, S1, S2 = 0, 0, 0

M1   = np.zeros( (armo , len( xt[0,:] ) ) )
M2   = np.zeros( (armo , len( xt[0,:] ) ) )
ante = np.zeros( ( 1 , len( xt[0,:] ) ) )
ArC  = np.zeros( ( 1 , armo ) )
ArCn = np.array( [np.arange( 1 , armo+1 ) ] )

for N in range( 1 , armo+1 ):
    
    An = float( an.subs( n , N ).evalf() )
        
    Bn = float( bn.subs( n , N ).evalf() )
    
    S1 = An*cos( (2*pi/T)*N*x )
    
    S2 = Bn*sin( (2*pi/T)*N*x )
    
    Lda = lambdify( x , S1 , 'numpy' )
    Ldb = lambdify( x , S2 , 'numpy' )
    
    M1[[N-1],:] = ( Lda( xt )+Ldb( xt ) )
    
    if (N == 1):
        M2[[N-1],:] = M1[[N-1],:]
        
    if (N > 1):
        M2[[N-1],:] = M2[[N-2],:] + M1[[N-1],:]
    
    ArC[[0],N-1] = np.max( M1[[N-1],:] )
      
Fourier = a0 + sum(M1 , axis=0)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( projection='3d' )
ax.plot_surface(ArCn.T , xt , M2)
```

The which is a representation in 3D of a periodic function in its harmonics. I'd like you to help me get two things.

The first one, Erase the white lines on the surface.

The second one (and harder), paint the surface with color. For example, where firsts harmonics are, painting a color green, then, while we go to the bottom in the graphic the green turns in blue. Is this possible? how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, try the `antialiased=False` option based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963004/continuous-shades-on-matplotlib-3d-surface).

For the second one, you need to plot your surface with a colormap.  There's a good example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html).

Comment: Thank you so much (Y)